# Azure Pipeline -Deleted Pipeline Status blocks new pipeline creation

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have deleted a pipeline but the pipeline status keeps showing.
I cannot create a new pipeline because the status is replacing the button "Set Up Build"

[image: Deleted pipeline status]

[image: Missing Set Up Build]

Deleted the pipeline using the following dialog - I don't see any option to delete status

[image: Delete Pipeline Dialog]

Deleted Pipeline does not produce any artifacts

Please Advise

Comment: Deleted Pipeline does not produce any artifacts - added to question - what is leased file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue.

This seems to be by design, when a definition is deleted, its statuses are preserved. That said, the statuses are posted on a commit, not on a branch, so once the branch gets updated with a new commit, it will get only a build status for the new definition.

To solve this issue, you can make some changes and do the commit option. And then you can see the **Set Up Build** Option.

Comment: it does work but it makes me add changes to branch.